# Appium not working with numeric keyboard

Tags: testing, keyboard, numeric, appium-android

I am trying to enter numbers in an edit field, though the field is focused Appium wasn't able to input the characters. I have tried it in multiple ways, all did not work.

Example 1:

```
driver.FindElementByXPath("field_to_fill").SendKeys("value");
```

Example 2:

```
_driver.PressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.KeycodeButton_8);
```

The field is EditText field, the Android platformVersion: 7.0, and I'm using C#.

Comment: It shouldn't be problem, do You have some DOM, some xml structure where You try to input this element, its location. Maybe You didn't instantiate this element properly? what type of field is this, ios/android which version, which language. Please provide more information, guessing its c#

Comment: Thanks @Kovacic, the field is EditText field which only accepts numeric input, so only numeric keyboard is displayed, android platformVersion: 7.0, c#.is the language.

Answer (score 2):

This is older, but maybe this will help someone in the future. I ran into this issue yesterday after the app under test changed from a qwerty keyboard to a number pad. (In Java) I was originally using `driver.sendKeys(stringOfDigits)`, which broke with the number pad keyboard showing. Neither `driver.setValue(stringOfDigits)` nor `driver.pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.NUMPAD_0));` worked either.

I found that `driver.pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.DIGIT_0));` worked. Or in my case, I was inputting a set of numbers from a string, so I used a loop:

```
for(char c : stringOfDigits.toCharArray()) {
  driver.pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.valueOf("DIGIT_" + c)));
}
```

I normally work with C#, but this project is in Java. Hopefully Appium is the same for both languages.

Comment: For those noobies like me ... You will not find this method under the `AppiumDriver`, but only under the `AndroidDriver`.

Answer (score 0):

I had simmilar issue on java, so I used two methods for workaround:

**1.method**
 - tap on the textField() 
 - get pageobject for UIAKeyboard, override numpad keyboard (fetch all buttons into page object)
 - used scripted method in pageobject to click on Number element. by name.

**2.method**
 - send keycodes (try using native driver AndroidDriver instead MobileDriver)

**3. method**

```
driver.sendkeyEvent(int key);
```

List Of Key codes:

> ```
> a - z-> 29 - 54
> "0" - "9"-> 7 - 16 
> BACK BUTTON - 4, 
> MENU BUTTON - 82 
> UP-19, 
> DOWN-20,
> LEFT-21, 
> IGHT-22 
> SELECT (MIDDLE) BUTTON - 23 
> SPACE - 62, 
> SHIFT - 59,
> ENTER - 66,
> BACKSPACE - 67
> ```

or for newer version

```
driver.pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.HOME);
```

**4. method (didn't tested)**
with x,y co-ordinate for each number (0-9 & .) and used driver.tap method

Comment: Using UIAutomatorviewer the keyboard is not selectable so thee's no way to get the key buttons into a page object. 2. Only PressKeyCode is available for key events. 3 Could you please explain the implementation of this?

Comment: sorry, wrote wrong, fixing it -driver.pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.HOME);, but that is what You've tried